# Clone of a functional 32GB SD card doesn't boot

Tags: boot, embedded, disk-image, arm64, clone

I have a Pine64 from the original Kickstarter (2016.) It boots from a 32GB SD card, which I've imaged from an Ubuntu16 Pine64 image file.

I've created a full disk backup of this 32GB SD card using AOMEI Backupper, and then restored the entire disk to a new 64GB SD card. **The restore is successful, and the disk looks OK, but the 64GB card won't boot.** Putting it in the Pine64 and powering on simply remains at a black screen (the original SD boots as soon as I plug the Pine64 in. I don't have to press a "Start" button or anything.)

I have also tried this with a 256 SD card, with the same results.

I have tried copying the entire 32GB SD card with DD in linux, and restoring via DD. Same problem.

What am I missing. Does the new disk have to have a boot sector activated or something?

I absolutely can't see the difference (see image for full details about the drive and copy)...

[image]

Comment: I don't see what is wrong. Cloning from a smaller drive to a bigger drive when there is an MSDOS partition table should work. So there must be some special problem. Maybe your computer cannot manage cards with size larger than 32 GB (seems unlikely but maybe, or maybe it would be able to read/write when already booted, but cannot boot from cards larger than 32 GB). You could try with a 32 GB card, but there is a problem: The target card must be at least as big as the source card, not one byte smaller for cloning to succeed, so check that e.g. with `lsblk -b -o name,size /dev/sd?`

Comment: Another possibility is that the cloned card is too slow or too fast for the computer to manage it (at boot). There are speed classes for cards and you can check that. - A third possibility is that you unplugged the card before the buffers were flushed so that the writing was not completely finished. In linux you can use the command `sync` and wait for it to finish (return to prompt). - A fourth possibility is that you cloned while booted into an operating system on the source drive. In that case things were changed during cloning and the result not reliable.

Comment: Actually, a restriction to 32 GB would be quite common in the embedded world, because 64 GB and above follo the SDXC standard, which is not supported by older BootROM code. In this case, it should be supported according to https://wiki.pine64.org/wiki/PINE_A64 . Anyhow, an old version of U-Boot may be on the disk, not supporting SDXC. Instead of guessing blindly, connect the serial console and read the debug messages. I hope your image is configured to output boot messages, otherwise you can fix that by stopping into U-Boot prompt.

Comment: As for reading the boot output, the Pine64 is connected to an LCD screen. When booting from the 32GB card, I do see text output before the GUI starts, but very little (not the rolling screen of text I'm used to with Linux.) With the larger cards I see nothing at all. Is this because of a quiet boot setting, or would a serial connection offer more?

Comment: A serial console does already show U-Boot output and allows you to stop at the U-Boot prompt for further debugging, for example change the kernel parameters for non-quite mode. In U-Boot prompt, you can also examine the SDcard with `mmc info` and the like: https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/cmd/mmc.html *(P. S. Write @username in your comments to get the user informed. I saw your answer by accident only)*